# Why does GetPrivateProfileString work with relative paths but not with filenames only?

Tags: winapi, path, filepath, ini

I have the following code that tries to read a INI file from a given location and if it fails it then tries to open in the current directory. My application has these two modes of execution, MAM and No MAM, hence the variable names.

```
{
    const char section[]="CONFIG";
    const char key[]="HEAP";
    char value[16];
    const char pwcfgFileMam[]="..\\pwcfg.ini";
    const char * const pwcfgFileNoMam = pwcfgFileMam + 1;
    long rc;
    DWORD rcProfile;

    value[0] = '\0';

    rcProfile= GetPrivateProfileString( section, key, "", value,
                                                sizeof(value)-1, pwcfgFileMam );

    if ( 0 == rcProfile )
    {
        rcProfile = GetPrivateProfileString( section, key, "", value,
                                              sizeof(value)-1, pwcfgFileNoMam );
    }

    // DO_SOMETHING(value);
}
```

According to the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the function should work only with [full paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths) which is another name for absolute paths, but this snippet work as long as you put a `.\` or `..\` prefix on the path. I previously had a bug in the 6th line, it was coded like this:

```
const char * const pwcfgFileNoMam = pwcfgFileMam + 3;
```

So, the function cannot work probably with only filenames, it needs at least a `.` or `..` to "find" the file. My boss told me that the function runs in another process or context or something, and thus it needs the "path" to force this other context to query the requirer for its `current working directory`. Anyone has a more throughly answer on why this function behaves like this? Is this just the case of a badly implemented and badly documented API?

Oh, by the way, I'm compiling this code with Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: You were meant to stop calling this function back in 1995. It is full of backwards compatibility. If your boss really said that, then you might need to get a new boss. Your current one doesn't have a clue what he is talking about. Or perhaps you misunderstood what he said. In any case, read the documentation which says "This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications" and find a different way to work with INI files.

Comment: Any references on the deprecation?

Comment: The documentation of the function. I even included the quote from that documentation.

Comment: This is explained right in the documentation for the `lpFileName` parameter.  "If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory."  It does work, but it doesn't do what you expect.  Please read the documentation you link to.  It works like this because more than two decades ago the Windows directory acted as the per-user profile directory when Windows ran from a file server.

Comment: My question is why './' and '../' paths are considered full paths.

Comment: You can *never* assume anything about what you get out of GetPrivateProfileString(), it has massive appcompat to ensure that programs written for Windows 3.x still run today.  Might not even read from the file, the string you get is totally unpredictable if it contains non-ASCII character.  Very expensive as well, typically ~50 msec.  Using it today is a *very* drastic mistake.

Comment: Right in your title you ask why it doesn't work with filenames.  It does.  The functionality is very simple: if you pass a plain filename it looks in the Windows directory, otherwise it uses the path you supply.  It looks like the documentation author tried to invert the sentence and erroneously used "full path" as the opposite of "plain filename".